# Form not consistent on browsers

Tags: html, forms, css

I am working on a website with an online form that feeds into an online banking system. My customer wants the form to conform to a certain style. I have tried all kinds of methods to make it look consistent on all browsers, but have been unsuccessful.

I have an image of what my customer wants[mock-up of online form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gk3e.jpg)

I can get it the way I want it in Explorer and Firefox, but it does not look the same on Chrome. Basically the customer everything to be centered with a uniform margin around the different elements.

I have used this code for the form:

```
<form name="McMForm" id="McMForm" method="post" target="_blank" action="http://domain/Login/Login.aspx">
<table style="width: 230px;">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="bgcolor: #ff0000; width: 230px; height: 36px;"><img src="images/online-banking.png" alt="Union State Bank Online Banking" title="Union State Bank Online Banking" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 180px; height: 30px;"><div id="McMUserNameDiv" style="color:#000000;">
<input name="UserName" type="text" id="McMUserID" placeholder="&nbsp;Username" style="color: #000; width: 176px;"/></td>
<td style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">
<input type="submit" value="LOGIN" style="background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;"/>
</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">mcmFixDomain();</script>
</form>
```

I have used the following code in the style sheet:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
color:    #003060;
}
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
color:    #003060;
}
input::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
color:    #003060;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
color:    #003060;
}
input:placeholder-shown {
color:  #ff0000;
}
```

Here's a link to the site: http://usbcc.com/new-responsive/

Comment: Where's the rest of the CSS you tried to make it look the same? Looking at the image, it's seems entirely possible to do.

Comment: I have several style sheets. It's just that the code I placed above was a direct effort to change the color of the place holder. I was trying, also, to do some inline styles with the form. Is it OK to link up an entire style sheet here?